# Streaming audio from IP camera to android (audiostream.cgi)

Tags: android, audio, stream

I have a IP camera. Which is able to stream sound according to api:

```
"用法：get /audiostream.cgi?user=&pwd=&streamid= user:用户名 pwd:密码 streamid:  
0->pcm 
1->adpcm 
2->mp3 
3->ogg 
4->aac"
```

How could I play this stream in android? I tried to stream with MediaPlayer, but all code snippets I could find was either only buffering all the time or saying resource was incorrect. Any help will be appreciated :).

Comment: I would like to know any method tooo... :/

Comment: Did you find how to decode returned stream???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution for this

```
    val socket = Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ip), port)
        val out = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)
        out.println("GET /audiostream.cgi?&loginuse=$login&loginpas=$pass&streamid=16 HTTP/0.9")
        out.println("Connection: Close")
        out.println()
        val inputStream = socket.getInputStream()
```

Comment: Maybe a bit more explanation would be helpful for most readers?